# Morera's Theorem in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

i have been thinking about this problem and would appreciate it if anyone can enlighten me.

Morera's Theorem states the following: Let $f(z)$ be a continuous function on a simply connected region, $D$. If for all loops in $D$, one has $\int_{C}f(z) dz=0$, then $f$ is holomorphic in $D$.

How can i also prove that the statement above is also true if $D$ is not simply connected? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f$ is holomorphic on $D$ if and only if for each $x\in D$, $f$ is holomorphic on some open disk in $D$ containing $x$.  Open disks are simply connected, so the theorem you cited can be applied locally for any region.

---

I will elaborate.

**Theorem** (from your question): Let $f(z)$ be a continuous function on a simply connected region, $D$. If for all loops in $D$, one has $\int_{C}f(z) dz=0$, then $f$ is holomorphic in $D$.

**Corollary**: Let $f(z)$ be a continuous function on a region, $D$. If for all loops in $D$, one has $\int_{C}f(z) dz=0$, then $f$ is holomorphic in $D$.

**Proof (that the corollary follows from the theorem)**:  Suppose $f$ and $D$ are as in the hypothesis of the corollary.  Let $z$ be a point in $D$.  Let $U$ be an open disk in $D$ containing $z$.  For all loops in $U$, by hypothesis $\int_{C}f(z) dz=0$.  Note that $U$ is simply connected, and $f$ is continuous on $U$, so by the theorem, $f$ is holomorphic on $U$.  Since $z$ was arbitrary and $f$ is holomorphic on a neighborhood of $U$, $f$ is holomorphic on $D$.

Comment: Hi Sir, thank you so much for your input! I am fairly new to this as i have just learnt this in class( I know it is not a good enough excuse) but could you kindly walk me through the steps to formulate the proof?

Comment: @Cleytus: I elaborated.